# Apply function array_map to an array with others array on it

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array which contains others arrays. How can apply the function to the array without calling every member of each array on the main array ($inputarray)?

```
$inputarray = array($product, $first_name, $last_name, $email_from, $preftel, $address, $zip, $city, $address_array, $zip_array, $city_array, $per, $datew, $hqty, $nrf, $tw, $meters, $comments);  

function create_safe_array($a){
  global $link;                                 
  return $link->real_escape_string($a);
}

$inputarray = array_map('create_safe_array', $inputarray);
```

**EDIT:**

```
require_once "sql.php";
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db) or die(".....");
$link->set_charset('UTF8');


$inputarray = array($product, $first_name, $last_name, $email_from, $preftel, $address, $zip, $city, $per, $datew, $hqty, $nrf, $tw, $meters, $comments);  

function create_safe_array($a){
  global $link;                                 
  return $link->real_escape_string($a);
}

$inputarray = array_map('create_safe_array', $inputarray);


$dateactial = date('d.m.Y');

$timeactual= date('H:i');

$sql = "INSERT INTO ORD (Date, Time, Prod, Name, LName, Mail, Tel, Address, ZIP, City,  Per, Date_When, Quantity, Nr_fo, Twag, Meters, Osservazioni) VALUES ('$dateactial ', '$timeactual', '$inputarray[0]', '$inputarray[1]', '$inputarray[2]', '$inputarray[3]', '$inputarray[4]', '$inputarray[5]', '$inputarray[6]', '$inputarray[7]', '$inputarray[8]', '$inputarray[9]', '$inputarray[10]', '$inputarray[11]', '$inputarray[12]', '$inputarray[13]', '$inputarray[14]')";

$link->query($sql) or die("....");
$link->close();
```

Comment: since it would appear that you're using the mysqli library, you might want to consider using prepared statements for your queries rather than escaping the variables.

Comment: As of PHP 5.3 you should use [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for implementing one-time callbacks.

Answer (score 6):

Do it recursively:

```
function create_safe_array($a){
  if(is_array($a)){
     return array_map('create_safe_array', $a);
  }
  global $link;                                 
  return $link->real_escape_string($a);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) instead of array_map (remembering that the array is passed by reference); and if you're on PHP 5.3.x or above, you can pas link using `use` rather than `global`.

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $inputarray,
    function (&$value) use ($link) {
        $value = $link->real_escape_string($value);

    }
);
```

but (as Spudley has commented) prepared statements are a cleaner, safer option when working with MySQLi

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
As I never used prepared statements, can you take me a complete example of a prepared statements for this case? Thank you

Comment: Without knowing your SQL, it's rather difficult to show you an example of a prepared statement